# db.createCollection is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am attempting to create a mongo instance however I am unable to access any of the helper methods from the mongodb nodejs driver.

My mongo instance is running within docker and the ports have been opened up to my local.

```
TypeError: db.createCollection is not a function
at /var/www/html/beacon/index.js:6:8
at args.push (/var/www/html/beacon/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:431:72)
at /var/www/html/beacon/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:254:5
at connectCallback (/var/www/html/beacon/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:933:5)
at /var/www/html/beacon/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:794:11
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Copied from w3schools...

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.createCollection("customers", function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Collection created!");
        db.close();
    });
});
```

No error is returned through the run, and no methods are exposed on the db object.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you put a`console.dir(db)` in line 6, (before `db.createCollection`) and show here the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB nodeJS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/mongodb-nodejs-error)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md) for Mongodb 3.0 you now get a client object containing the database object instead:

So you need the `db` object that points to the database you want to use, in your case mydb. Try this:

```
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {   //here db is the client obj
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbase = db.db("mydb"); //here
    dbase.createCollection("customers", function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Collection created!");
        db.close();   //close method has also been moved to client obj
    });
});
```

Comment: Will mark as correct answer when the timing allows it. Odd in my opinion with the db url path however thank you :)

Comment: Surprised to see that this isn't documented on driver's page in examples, but only in change log.

Answer (score 3):

You're not the one facing this issue. Seems that 3.0 mongo driver has a bug or these are just breaking backwards compatibility changes. Take a look here:
[db.collection is not a function when using MongoClient v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/mongodb-nodejs-error)

To use DB name in the URL, you need to uninstall MongoDB, change to `"mongodb": "^2.2.33"` in dependencies and do `npm install` to install the new version.

Or you can install specific version with command `npm install mongodb@2.2.33 --save`

Comment: Not sure if you are actually answering the question

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error while running `createCollection()` from the command line Mongo shell tool `mongosh`.

> TypeError: db.createCollection is not a function

In my case, I could not get create collection to work, so I resorted to just inserting a document into the collection which I wanted to create.  By default, Mongo will create a collection by that name on the fly, assuming you have the permissions to do so.  This is not an ideal solution, but it allowed me to proceed at least.